# React-Native Native Controls Support

Tags: react-native

Usually cross-platform frameworks support a subset of native controls but never all.  For example, Xamarin.Forms supports a set of native controls on IOS/Android/UWP but not all.

In order to add a native control to a Xamarin.Forms, we need to convert the native UI control into a compatible Xamarin.Forms control.

How is this in React-Native?  Does React-Native support all native controls or only a subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native has most native UI components ported, but not all. Just like with Xamarin.Forms, in order to make the code cross-platform, some primitives has been renamed: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html

If there are custom or third party components which you want available, then you will have to wrap it for each platform. Guides for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html). This includes creating a `ViewManager` for each platform which lets you control the native UI view via a bridge to the JavaScript.

In short, it can support all.